# Can I force Linux to boot its initializations parallel?

Tags: boot, startup, parallelism

I was wondering if I could manage to initialize drivers, services etc. (all these jobs what Linux does during startup) in parallel instead of sequentially. I want to aggressively lower the boot time. I know some services depend on each other but to make an easy example: during probing the network devices, it shall take care of the audio too, instead of waiting 10 s until the network is ready.

I heard of concepts like *systemd* and *InitNG* but I'm sure there has to be other methods. Isn't there an option or flag for the kernel itself to boot this way?

Comment: the kernel already does that. you have to look into the init system in order to achieve parallel boot. The things you are talking about (network ready) etc. are all userspace related and have not much to do with the kernel

Comment: You want to look at [LPC: Booting Linux in five seconds](http://lwn.net/Articles/299483/)

Comment: Take a look on systemd : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd

From the main description:
systemd is a system and service manager for Linux, compatible with SysV and LSB init scripts. systemd provides aggressive parallelization capabilities, uses socket and D-Bus activation for starting services, offers on-demand starting of daemons, keeps track of processes using Linux control groups, supports snapshotting and restoring of the system state, maintains mount and automount points and implements an elaborate transactional dependency-based service control logic.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same. But i thought the kernel gives up booting some jobs parallel due to security reasons or whatever. So I guess, the biggest part for my concern seems to be the init system? Are there alternatives to systemd and InitNG ?

Comment: Take a look here:
http://www.linux.org/threads/init-and-its-alternatives.4876/

Comment: @user3085931 Are there any specific reasons, why you'd want an alternative to systemd? From a technical viewpoint, it is far superior to any other existing init-/service-management solution.

Comment: just because it comes with a large number of dependencies, which causes a "waste" of memory on the embedded device

Comment: @user3085931 systemd is anything else but bloated. See also [item#12 here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/the-biggest-myths.html). Sure, it requires a bit more storage (not memory) than other init-systems, but you'll save this on the other hand by not installing all the other components you'd need on a non-systemd setup. Besides that, you can still to choose not to build selected systemd components which you don't want to have on your setup.

Comment: @UlrichDangel,@Anthon,@Jasonwryan,@slm,@Jordanm: This question was clear to me. The only problem was that the questioner could not clearly distinguish between kernel boot and system boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `CONCURRENCY` variable in `/etc/init.d/rc`, you have several choices.
When set to `makefile`, then the init process does it in parallel.

There are different comments depending your distribution:

```
#
# Check if we are able to use make like booting.  It require the
# insserv package to be enabled. Boot concurrency also requires
# startpar to be installed.
#
CONCURRENCY=makefile
```

```
# Specify method used to enable concurrent init.d scripts.
# Valid options are 'none' and 'makefile'.  Obsolete options
# used earlier are 'shell' and 'startpar'.  The obsolete options
# are aliases for 'makefile' since 2010-05-14.  The default since
# the same date is 'makefile', as the init.d scripts in Debian now
# include dependency information and are ordered using this
# information.  See insserv for information on dependency based
# boot sequencing.
#CONCURRENCY=makefile
CONCURRENCY=none
```

See also the line in your `init` script:

```
eval "$(startpar -p 4 -t 20 -T 3 -M $1 -P $previous -R $runlevel)"
```

See also `man startpar`

Good hint from Timo: The [Bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) package lets you visualize your boot process.

Good reads: [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), [SysV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V), [History](http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix/history_timeline.html)

[edit]

It is often difficult to use bootchart, so here a howto:

**Bootchart Micro Howto**

- install it  `apt-get install bootchart2 pybootchartgui`
- reboot
- in the boot screen of grub press <kbd>e</kbd> for edit.
  then find the line with kernel boot parameters and add `init=/sbin/bootchartd`
- press <kbd>F10</kbd> for boot
- after you OS is up and running open a terminal window and run `sudo pybootchartgui`
- you'll find your `bootchart.png` in the working directory

Comment: sounds like I have to take care of threading ?

Comment: `startpar` takes care of parallelism.

Comment: the startpar is new for me, thanks I'll have a look on it

Comment: You normally don't need to touch startpar. I'd first try bootchart, then you know which process slows down the boot sequence. The makefile option sometimes considered unstable, so you need also take look at the dependencies of the start scripts.